# How to serialize a Json partially?

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I have a huge json (20 mb, 6000+ records) that If I use decode it takes ages, then I started using serialize to try to parse it in pieces. But I'm having trouble to parse it (getting null when I serialize it, funny enough I don't specify as? [String:Any] I actually get the json)

is there a better way to parse a Json partially?

Json structure

```
[
  {
    "page": 1,
    "total": 100,
    "data": [
      {
        "address": "677 Quincy Street #1B",
        "neighborhood": "Stuyvesant Heights",
        "zipcode": "11221",
        "latitude": 40.68935935,
        "longitude": -73.93179845,
        "bedroom": "2 beds",
        "bath": "1.5 baths",
        "area": null,
        "status": "current",
        "photos": [
          "https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/b444ec7e07f1bb83f27c6dfa2167e92a-se_extra_large_1500_800.jpg"
        ],
        "video": null,
        "description": "NO FEE!!Luxury 2 BR / 1.5 Bath DUPLEX Apartment",
        "new_listing": 1,
        "date_available": "Available Now",
        "open_house": null,
        "price": 2999,
        "dishwasher": false,
        "washer_and_dryer": false,
        "pets_allowed": true,
        "live_in_super": false,
        "elevator": false,
        "url": "https://streeteasy.com/building/677-quincy-street-brooklyn/1b"
      },
]
}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Your JSON is an array at top level, and `as? [String: Any]`, it means as dictionary, that's why it fails...

Comment: Side note: You are deserializing Data into Dictionary/Array, then converting it again some part into `Data`, then calling JSONDecoder (that will call also the JSONSerialization again into Dictionary/Array, and then map the values), I'm not sure it will be really faster. Maybe not "unitary", as you are doing `jsonPage[0]`, maybe with chunks of 200 objects instead of one...

Comment: thanks @Larme, I changed my code to ```let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]]``1 and it's retrieving the json, now I just need to capture the first 100 listings

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, but sadly serialization doesn't help with the load speed, I was thinking to do "pagination with the first 100 items" but swift needs to parse the entire json first.

```
//serialization baby!
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]]
                        
                            //make it an array
                            let first100Listings = json!.first!["data"] as? NSArray

                            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: first100Listings!, options: [])
                            let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([Listings].self, from: jsonData)

                            self.listingsZ = responseModel
```